# Linux TCP socket in blocking mode

Tags: linux, sockets, tcp, network-programming, network-protocols

When I create a TCP socket in blocking mode and use the `send` (or `sendto`) functions, when the will the function call return?

Will it have to wait till the other side of the socket has received the data? In that case, if there is traffic jam on the internet, could it block for a long time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both the sender and the receiver (and possibly intermediaries) will buffer the data.

Sending data successfully is no guarantee that the receiving end has received it.

Normally writes to a blocking socket, won't block as long as there is space in the sending-side buffer.

Once the sender's buffer is full, then the write WILL block, until there is space for the entire write in it.

If the write is partially successful (the receiver closed the socket, shut it down or an error occurred), then the write might return fewer bytes than you had intended. A subsequent write should give an error or return 0 - such conditions are irreversible on TCP sockets.

Note that if a subsequent send() or write() gives an error, then some previously written data could be lost forever. I don't think there is a real way of knowing how much data actually arrived (or was acknowledged, anyway).

Comment: A write cannot return zero in blocking mode. Either something is written or you get -1 and an errno.

Comment: @EJP: a write CAN return zero if the peer closes the connection gracefully. An abnormal disconnect would cause a -1, though.

Comment: @RemyLebeau-TeamB No. That's only on read() and recv(). A write() or send() to a closed connection will eventually return -1 with errno == ECONNRESET.

Comment: @EJP what happens if the received calls shutdown()?

Comment: @EJP: I do not know about Linux, but on Windows I have seen `send()` return 0 when the receiver has called `shutdown()` with the `SD_RECEIVE` or `SD_BOTH` flag specified to indicate a graceful disconnnect. An `ECONNRESET` error (`WSAECONRESET` on Windows) would indicate the connection was forcibly aborted instead.  For both `send()` and `recv()`, returning 0 (preferably after calling `select()` first to determine writability/readability) indicates a graceful disconnect.

Comment: @RemyLebeau-TeamB When you write to a connection that has already been closed by the peer, the peer must issue an RST, which manifests itself at the sender as ECONNRESET. This is defined in the RFCs. It is not optional or platform-dependent. Returning zero  would be contrary to the contract that all bytes are transferred in blocking mode,or an error issued.